# GraphX in Spark using Scala language cannot be defined

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

[image]

Graphx Cannot be defined using Scala language.
this is sbt file:

```
name := "spark_scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.10"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "3.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mlLib" % "3.3.1",
  "org.squeryl" % "squeryl" % "0.9.5-2",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you change the version of SPark to 3.3.0, and scala as well for 2.1